# Arduino Adafruit NeoMatrix library

Tags: arduino

I am testing Adafruit_NeoMatrix library, the example attached:
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NeoMatrix/blob/master/examples/tiletest/tiletest.pde
and I can't figure out the relation of the text length and the if sentence:

```
 if(--x < -36) {
```

more text length imply increase the numer "36", but I don't really see the relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-36` defines the maximum displacement based on font width, screen width and text length. The standard font of Adafruit_GFX is 6px per character. You need this cursor value to render the font characters correctly.

Variables you need...

```cpp
char exampleText[32] = "This is a test";
int  pixelPerChar = 6;
int  maxDisplacement;
```

Calculate the maximum displacement at the beginning ...

```cpp
void setup()
{
  maxDisplacement = strlen(exampleText) * pixelPerChar + matrix.width();
  //...
}
```

In the loop function...

```cpp
//...
if (--x < -maxDisplacement)
{
    x = matrix.width();
}
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to look at this if you write the if statement in the following equivalent way:

```
x--;
if(x < -36) { ... }
```

x is the cursor location which is the beginning of the string. At the beginning it is equal to the length of the row which means that the string is hidden to the right of the screen. Each iteration the cursor is moved one step to the left, untill it reaches the coordinate -36. If the string is shorter than 36, it will be hidden to the left of the screen. Then the whole routine is reinitilized with different color.